# Как разбить число на разряды (тысячи, миллионы и т.д.)?

Tags: php

Фото. Лайки. При достижении 1 000 или 10 000 лайков, цифры выводятся таким образом:

> Like 1000 или Like 10000

Интересует, как разделять тысячные, миллионные и т.п значения, чтобы например, было так

> Like 10 000.

Возможно, в PHP есть стандартная функция, которая этим занимается?

Comment: Здесь есть ответ на ваш вопрос - [https://www.pandoge.com/stati_i_sovety/razbivaem-chisla-na-razryady-na-javascript-php](https://www.pandoge.com/stati_i_sovety/razbivaem-chisla-na-razryady-na-javascript-php)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
number_format(10000, 0, '', ' ');
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.number-format.php

Answer (score 10):

Внезапно, для форматирования чисел используется [number_format](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.number-format.php).

Сигнатура:

```
string number_format ( float $number , int $decimals = 0 , string $dec_point = "." , string $thousands_sep = "," )
```

> number
>     Форматируемое число.
>   decimals
>     Устанавливает число знаков после запятой.
>   dec_point
>     Устанавливает разделитель дробной части.
>   thousands_sep
>     Устанавливает разделитель тысяч.

Пример:

```
echo number_format(100000, 0, '.', ' ');
```

Answer (score 3):

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.number-format.php

```
$number = 1234.56;
$formatted_number = number_format($number, 2, ',', ' ');
// 1 234,56
```

Answer (score 1):

[`number_format()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.number-format.php) — Форматирует число с разделением групп

Answer (score 0):

```
number_format($n, strlen(explode('.',$n)[1]),',',' ');
```

Comment: Чего-то жуть какая-то...

Comment: Что именно не ясно? просто добавлена установка кол-ва знаков после запятой.

Answer (score 0):

$str = 10000;
number_format($str, 0, '.', ' ');

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]