# PHP: Вставить пробел каждые N символов но начиная с конца

Tags: php, строки

Как вставить пробел на РНР каждые N символов но начиная отсчет не с начала строки а с конца. Например чтобы с `1234567` получить `1 234 567` (если каждые три символа). `chunk_split` и `wordwrap` работают лишь со значениями больше 0

Можно в принципе вот так:

```
$reverse = strrev("1234567");
$withSpaces = chunk_split($reverse, 3, ' ');
echo strrev($withSpaces);
```

Но может есть что то проще

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Работа с числами в PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420465/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[number_format](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.number-format.php)

Если вкратце:

1. Вводимое число
2. Сколько символов после "точки"
3. Разделитель "точки"
4. Разделитель тысячных (каждый третий с конца)

Пример:

```
echo number_format(1000000, 0, '.', ' '); // 1 000 000

echo number_format(1000000, 2, '.', ','); // 1,000,000.00
```